# Disable/Delay Android Lock Screen Programmatically

Tags: android

I’d like to `disable/delay` the lock screen programmatically.  In looking into this, `KeyguardManager` is depreciated/doesn't work consistently, `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` is not an option because I want to do this in the background, I don't want to use WakeLock for battery reasons, Device Administration does not appear to be capable of this and, while `SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT` is available to control when the screen sleeps, I was unable to find a similar timeout for the screen lock.

What am I missing here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

try this, it will keep awake the screen/ display , as long as the activity is on top.
    `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

Also this does not require any permission in manifest.

Answer (score 3):

the  answer of *@nandeesh* is working but it's *deprecated* , to disable lock screen use flags :

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

You can disable the keyguard using this.

Comment: Yes, and it is depreciated/doesn’t work consistently (per my original post).