# Android: remove or disable programmatically the Lock Screen on Samsung Galaxy S2 device

Tags: android, android-activity

**The problem** My Android automated tests are unreliable, because the tested activities are sometimes running and are sometimes paused.

**The cause** If my android device (a Samsung Galaxy S2) has its Lock Screen on, all activities are immediately put in Pause mode.

How can I programmatically disable the Lock Screen while my tests are running?

Here is what I tried and that produced no result at all (i.e., Lock Screen still active and pausing my activities).

- Add the `android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD` permission and use `KeyguardLock.disableKeyguard()` as explained in the [android doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html#UnlockDevice).
- Set Window flags: FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED, FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON, FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD.
- Use `WakeLock.acquire()` with `PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK`, `PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP`, `PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE` and `PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` parameters.
- `adb shell input keyevent 82`

Comment: Please refer to my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021800/disable-delay-android-lock-screen-programmatically/19955030#19955030

Answer (score 7):

In Kotlin,

For **Api level 28** or less, you can simply add below method in your activity that needs to be opened:

```
override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow()
    toBeShownOnLockScreen()
}

private fun toBeShownOnLockScreen() {
    window.addFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
    )
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
        setTurnScreenOn(true)
        setShowWhenLocked(true)
    } else {
        window.addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                    or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
        )
    }
}
```

And to make it work on **Android Pie and above**, in addition to above step, we need to set in AndroidManifest as well:

```
<activity
    android:name=".view.activity.LockScreenActivity"
    android:showOnLockScreen="true"
    android:showWhenLocked="true"
    android:turnScreenOn="true" />
```

I have tested this code from Api level 21 to 29, and works like charm!

**Update:** some Samsung devices (Samsung Galaxy S7 edge in my case) may fail to work if `toBeShownOnLockScreen()` is called inside `onAttachedToWindow()`. So, there you simply call `toBeShownOnLockScreen()` inside `onCreate()` of Activity. That's it.

Comment: I noticed that after one lock and unlock UI starts to behave strangely - for example, messenger buble disappears, and after the second lock UI freezes. Something underneath happens but I cannot see it - so I click the button, something happens but I cannot see the result.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working for me. Just a quick note: why did you duplicate the `showWhenLocked` and `turnScreenOn` attributes in the XML? You've already activated them in the Java code.

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI Didn't get a chance to look into this. But AFAIK, the required was achieved only by writing at both places. Can you re-verify and update here in comments, if the code is working or not.

Answer (score 6):

You can disable your lockscreen by using following code.Include this code in oncreate of your activity .

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "INFO");
        wl.acquire();

KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        kl = km.newKeyguardLock("name");
        kl.disableKeyguard();
```

In manifest include permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

Comment: What you describe corresponds to the third and first solutions (respectively) I tried. They have no effect at all on the Lock Screen of my Samsung Galaxy S2.

Answer (score 5):

```
android:keepScreenOn='true'
```

use this attribute in rootView like this

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android=`http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`
    xmlns:app=`http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`
    android:layout_width=`match_parent`
    android:layout_height=`match_parent`
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
```

Comment: Although this prevents the screen from being off, this does not answer the question at all

Answer (score 0):

Up to date Kotlin code for skipping the lock screen:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val keyguardManager = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
    keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null)
    setShowWhenLocked(true)
} else {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD)
}
```

For more elaborate explanation on keyguard flags, go [here](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/how-to-make-your-android-app-re-appear-without-a-lock-screen-64e897680afe).