# programatically remove make the screen lock as "none"

Tags: android, screen, screen-lock

I am on a project in which I will use the android 4.4 version on a non-touch based display unit. Hence i want the screen lock to be "none" by default and this i need to make in the build.
So is there any XML file or variable which i can modify so that by default the screen lock will be "none" instead of "slide"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18890347/3711660

Comment: @Toumash  this is to do if something needs to be done from an application.. for me in general place need to be changed. so that in the bootup itself it will be set to none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the following solution:

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock kl = km.newKeyguardLock(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
kl.disableKeyguard();
```

in my  launcher code.

Comment: But after restart device security automatically set to previous value @JVN