# How do disable lockscreen in android?

Tags: android, lockscreen, device-admin

I have my app registered as device administrator, with the appropriate lock screen permissions. I can access the method to lock the device, but cannot disable lockscreen.

Is there an API method available that will disable lock?

Comment: if you want to push any activiy on top of lockscreen??

Comment: @munkay how u  achive this ?

Comment: @Erum as mentioned in the answer below, this is not supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there an API method available that will disable lock?
>   **NO**

**this is not supported, for security reasons.**

all of that stuff was deprecated

[Disable/Delay Android Lock Screen Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021800/disable-delay-android-lock-screen-programmatically)

[Android: remove or disable programmatically the Lock Screen on Samsung Galaxy S2 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890143/android-remove-or-disable-programmatically-the-lock-screen-on-samsung-galaxy-s2)

Comment: In that case, what are the alternatives? I wanted a custom lock screen or just customize the current lock screen with some text and call functionality. Many were disabling it, and launching their activities as a lock screen with Home and Back buttons disabled. How else can we implement this?