# How to programmatically enable/disable lock screen and dial key pad in phone settings?

Tags: android, android-settings

I am trying to *programmatically* disable/enable the dial keypad and the lock screen, but I am unable to do so as I cannot find the relevant constants in **Settings.System** or related paths.

How to perform these operations programmatically?

Comment: Are you trying to open your activity when screen is locked and open dialpad just after opening you activity?

Comment: I am not doing that at all, I just want to know how to programmatically disable those features in phone *settings*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do disable lockscreen in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632217/how-do-disable-lockscreen-in-android)